# View boost::multi_index_container data in debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, boost

I am attempting to investigate memory dump of the program which uses boost.multi_index library on Windows using Visual Studio. I have sources, executable and debug symbols corresponding to that memory dump. However, debugger can't show actual data stored in the multi_index container the same way as it does, for example, for std::map or std::vector. Installing this https://cppvisualizers.codeplex.com/ plugin did not help - still see only some internal data members without actual data. Multi-index I am trying to inspect has 2 hashed indices. Does anyone know how to get to the data based only on the raw values visible in the VS debugger?

Comment: you'd have to create some visualizers for b::m_i_c. Contribute them back if you make it!

Comment: I better give up using these containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 2017, the plugin "C++ Debugger Visualizers for VS2017" worked for me: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArkadyShapkin.CDebuggerVisualizersforVS2017

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "essential part" here. For me the essential part was to install a plugin. Is it enough if I update the answer with the name of the plugin or what is your suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, that's fine